Do I need an extra driver to use PS/2 port computer mouse?
There are several PS/2 mice with an 800/1000 DPI optical sensor, three buttons, and a scroll-wheel. Several modern motherboards have a PS/2 port, such as the MSI Pro B650M-P, ASUS Prime H610M-A, ASRock B450M Steel Legend, GIGABYTE B560M DS3H V2 and ASUS ROG Strix X870E-E.
Do I need extra driver to use PS/2 port computer mouse? Where can I find them? Any reference of interface specification of PS/2?

Which operating system do you want to use with your mice?

You want to connect some PS/2 mice to modern computers with PS/2 ports. Simply connect them. Do we have to assume you are using Windows or some other OS, and which version of any OS? How is this a retrocomputing question?

What’s the long product list for?

@Justme I happen to think this is not a particularly great question for other reasons, but how is PS/2 not a retrocomputing topic?

@user3840170 Indeed, the PS/2 part is the only retro thing. But the question really is about "Are these new mice I can buy from shops compatible with these new motherboards I can buy from shops"? For comparison, people might have USB mice and USB motherboards that are 25 years old.

I am unaware of any operating system able to run on these motherboards that do not support PS/2.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen at least the H610M-A should be able to boot DOS, which needs a separate driver.

There's definitely an on-topic question hidden here somewhere (as evidenced by Sneftel's answer), but I'm not sure what the point of this question is. PS/2's a standard protocol, so I removed the list of mice – though it might be useful to add some back, like the contemporary F8E850-OPT 5-button mouse. Do we need the list of motherboards?

There's a frequently-copied 2001 article by Adam Chapweske, entitled "The PS/2 Mouse Interface", that might be relevant. (I also found its first link, "PS/2 Mouse/Keyboard Protocol" (1999).) This describes Microsoft's 5-button extension, as well as the regular 3-button mode.

@StephenKitt I missed the word “modern”, sorry.  Ms-DOS needs s driver to use a mouse, period

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ah, I thought perhaps you were referring to the fact that many modern motherboards can no longer boot DOS, in which scenario your comment applies literally!

@StephenKitt as MS-DOS became basically a Windows98-loader thirty years ago and is not really what people expect from an operating system today and Windows know all about PS/2 hardware, it can be argued that DOS is not included in the question

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this is Retro.SE, so …

@wizzwizz4 Agreed this could have been acceptable if improved – but now that an accepted answer is already posted, I doubt the asker would be willing to do it.

The PS/2 interface is built deeply into the motherboard chipset, and specifies all “normal” communication between peripheral and host. If the computer can run an OS, that OS can use PS/2 mice without additional third-party drivers.
Some PS/2 mice and keyboards have vendor-specific extensions to the PS/2 command set which will require extra drivers; things like controlling sensitivity, programming macros, using vendor-specific buttons, or mouse inputs beyond three buttons and two axes. None of these will be required if you’re just using the thing as a basic 2/3-button mouse. However, they will be required to use a scroll wheel or any buttons beyond the third.

For retro operating systems this isn’t necessarily true — DOS in particular needs device drivers for mice.

@StephenKitt MOUSE.COM is not a third-party driver.

It wasn’t included with retail MS-DOS; each mouse came with a driver disk containing the appropriate driver (including Microsoft mice).

Yes, but Microsoft’s MOUSE.COM (directly included in later versions of DOS) supported all PS/2 mice regardless of vendor. That’s my point: it’s not a third party vendor-specific protocol at base.

The programming interface wasn’t vendor-specific (otherwise it wouldn’t have been much use), but (a) mouse.com generally wasn’t included even in later versions of MS-DOS, and (b) it didn’t support all PS/2 mice. Most PCs shipped with the appropriate mouse driver, so the distinction might seem pedantic, but a base installation of MS-DOS didn’t always include it (including 6.22).

@Sneftel I am also pretty sure that mouse.com does not come with DOS and at least the version I had did not have support for PS/2 mice, and why would a driver for MS mice support extensions for other mice like three or more buttons? The MS mouse.com did not even support other serial mice with Mouse Systems serial protocol.

@Justme see https://packet-radio.net/ms-dos-6-22-files/ .

As for the three or more buttons thing, read my answer in its entirety.

@Sneftel Nice try but that's not an original DOS bootdisk, so it does not apply. It's made by some hobbyist. It did not even come with CD-ROM drivers and yet they are there. With file dates from 1999 even. Please refer to an actual, original DOS install disk.

@Justme to be fair, later versions of Microsoft’s driver did support PS/2 mice. I don’t remember if they support the middle button and I can’t check right now. Most (not all) PS/2 mice used the common protocol by default, so they worked with the Microsoft driver in a basic mode.

@Justme The combative tone is unwelcome.
